# django how to make custom url

Tags: python, django

hey guys i have been learning Django for about 3 week now and i am just curious is there anyway to set custom url for main page(the first page shown when starting the server) because i try to do it like the code below but still it give me error if anyone know please help if not hmm...maybe that how Django operate i think haha. Thanks

```
// Django api
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('account/',include("useraccount.urls")),
]

//useraccount
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('login',views.login,name="login"),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a url for home page you can do something like this in your main url

```
path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

Comment: but can it used instead ' ' used like 'username' in project(Django main) url and in app url 'login' so that when the server start it not start from localhost/ it start from localhost/username/login? sorry for my bad English

Comment: usually, login link are provided in your home page and when user clicks it will go to /login url, and after login you can send him to either profile page or some other place

Comment: hmm..alright thanks mate i just trying to make so that it automate user to login in page when the server start..